# Show calendar for a Many2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I display each employee on the calendar view

```html
    employee_id0 = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employee', index=True)
```

```html
<record id="calendar_planning_working_dashboard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">my_model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar date_start="date_r1" date_stop="date_r2" color="employee_id0" mode="month" avatar_model="hr.employee" quick_add="False">
            <field name="display_name" />

        </calendar>
    </field>
</record>
```